# symfony - IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY not working

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm starting with journey with Symfony.
At this I trying to secure my auth routes (I'm using FOSUserBundle) so I do:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/logowanie$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/rejestracja, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetowanie-hasla, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/backstage/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/profile/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

However, I can always go to these routes whether I'm logged in or not.
Where is my bad?

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: website.home
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/logowanie$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/rejestracja, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetowanie-hasla, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/backstage/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/profile/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: show full security config

Comment: It is not really clear from your question, but I guess, in your case, any user can go to `/backstage/` and `/profile/`?

Comment: @MaxP. added into question. Jovan Perovic Not only. I want to prevent access for logged user to this routes (logowanie - login, rejestracja - register, etc.)

Comment: No you can't do this that way. If user is logged in also have role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`. This is how role hierarchy work (otherwise there is no reason called it "hierarchy").

Comment: @malcolm So what's the best solution? Override view methods for this routes with added condition for logged user?

Comment: `- { path: ^/logowanie$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICADED_FULLY }`

Comment: In case someone runs into this issue in >2023: Use the `PUBLIC_ACCESS` role in more recent symfony versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should restrict access to logged-in users, now if a user is logged in, also has the role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`, this is role hierarchy.

```
- { path: ^/logowanie$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: There is not any mention, in the documentation, about using logical operators in access_control -> role attribute. Is it working in any version of Symfony?

Comment: I think that this is a part of Symfony expresion language.

Comment: thats something you can only write in the `allow_if` https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html#securing-by-an-expression

Answer (score 7):

You can use *PUBLIC_ACCESS* instead off *IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY*

```
access_control:
      - { path: ^/logowanie$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

best regards ;)

Comment: Ref https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/42510/files